# How to use \u or \x in regular expression matching? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I couldn't figure this out after spending 2 days of Google search and trials. 
**Question:** Is there any way to use a regular expression that includes `\u` or `\x`?

**What I want to do:** I am reading a long text in string, and I need to check if that text contains the following pattern:

***\20\999\u[0-f]{4}***

So for example, if the text includes ***\20\30\u001a***, it needs to be true and I actually need to retrieve this value. (By the way, the real regular expression is way longer than this, but I shortened it for convenience.)

**The code I have that is not working:**

```
private string re = @"\20\999\u[0-9a-f]{4}";
private Match CheckIfMatches(string textToBeChecked)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(this.re, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return regex.Match(textToBeChecked)
}

private void DoSomeOperation(string textToBeChecked)
{
    string s = "";
    try
    {
        Match matchResult = CheckIfMatches(textToBeChecked);
        if(result.Success)
        {
            s = result.Value;
            //Do more operations
        }
        else
        { 
            //Do more operations
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         //Do error handling
    }
}
```

When I test-run this program with some text, it returns an error and it goes to the exception with **Insufficient Hexadecimal Digits**. I know this is happening because the regular expression contains ***\u***. But I actually need to include this in the regular expression.

I tried removing `@`, and also adding one extra `\` to see if it makes any difference, but it didn't.

How can I use a regular expression in C# with `\u` or `\x`?

**Edit:**
Below is a part of the whole string stored in `textToBeChecked` as the entire string is too long, and also it is confidential.

***Test sample test sample test sample \03\02\0\u0010\ test sample test sample***

Something like above is stored in this variable. And the actual code I am using is

```
private string re = @"\\03\\02\\0\\u[0-9a-f]{4}";
```

`result.Success` in my code in the original question returns `false` to this.

Comment: Maybe you want `@"\\20\\999\\u[0-9a-f]{4}"`?

Comment: Side note: " \20\30\u001a" *does not* match the pattern you are looking for. Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code as it is not clear what you are getting wrong (in addition to not knowing how to create regex for "\").

Comment: I cannot figure out why this does not match the pattern. I tried the code with the suggestion @WiktorStribiżew gave me. The error disappeared, but the match fails.

Comment: Add the exact string or, better, string literal with the text you need to handle, to the question. What is in `textToBeChecked`?

Comment: I edited my original question. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: But you have ``\03\02\0\u0010\``. Try `Regex.Replace(textToBeChecked, @"\s*(?:\\\d+)+\\u[0-9a-f]{4}\\", "")` to remove the matches, see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/E3C07K)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The replace method did not replace anything. It seems like after running this method, the stored text is still the same as the original.

Comment: Then you are mistaken about your *literal text*. LITERAL TEXT != STRING LITERAL.